# httpClient.PutAsync() not updating, 415 Unsupported media type

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building a `Rest API` and a `Rest Client`, the api url is `https://localhost:44341` and the client url is `https://localhost:44305/`, specifically I want to be able to edit pages in the client for a small custom cms.

Anyway, to view a page in the client, I do this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(long id)
{
    Page page = new Page();
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44341/api/Pages/" + id);
        string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        page = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Page>(apiResponse);
    }
    return View(page);
}
```

And it works, I get the actual page data from the API, however the PUT method in the client is not working, this is it:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Page page)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using var response = await httpClient.PutAsync("https://localhost:44341/api/Pages/" + 
              page.Id, new StringContent(page.ToString()));

        string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    return Redirect(Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString());
}
```

When I submit the form for the above method it just redirects to the previous request but the changes aren't saved.

Here's the `put` method from the api:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> PutPage(long id, Page page)
{
    if (id != page.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    context.Entry(page).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return NoContent();
}
```

When I inspect using breakpoints, I can see that the `response` in the `POST` method says `415 unsupported media type`

Comment: Side note, but [you are using HttpClient wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: So what is the debugger telling you? Do you enter PutPage() at all?  What are the returned stuscodes?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I just edited my Q, no I do not seem to be entering PutPage at all.

Comment: What's the generated content type of the put request? StringContent defaults to text/plain I think. Can you deserialize text/plain back into a Page object? What format are you expecting your Put handler to process - how have you set up serialization? JSON?

Comment: @Rup The API put method is in my Q if that is what you're referring to, I am expecting it to process JSON I guess but I don't know how to send JSON via httpClient

Comment: "I don't know how to send JSON via httpClient".... put "httpclient send as json" into a search engine and you'll get a lot of suggestions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `415 unsupported media type` status code means that

> The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of
>   the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for
>   the requested method.

When you use `new StringContent(page.ToString())` then the media type for the [StringContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Http_StringContent__ctor_System_String_) created defaults to text/plain.

You need to send content in json format:

```
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(page, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");   
using var response = await httpClient.PutAsync($"https://localhost:44341/api/Pages/{page.Id}", content);
```